# hdfs filesystem: metadata created but file not found

Tags: linux, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I am trying to run a map reduce job which creates some intermediate files that are later used by the code running in node manager.

The code works fine when run in linux file system. But when the same is run in hdfs, none of the intermediate files are created. 
The same goes for a result file that is updated as the code runs.

In both the cases I can find the metadata but when I am trying to look for the file it's not there

**Here is what happens when I look for "rule.txt".**

inside hdfs:

**looking for rule.txt:**

```
hdfs dfs -ls /home/hduser/C45/

14/11/24 13:30:13 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable 
Found 2 items 
drwxr-xr-x   - hduser supergroup        0 2014-11-23 19:06 /home/hduser/C45/bank/output   
drwxr-xr-x   - hduser supergroup          0 2014-11-24 13:20 /home/hduser/C45/bank/outputIntermediate
```

**when trying to check all subfolders:**

```
hdfs dfs -ls /home/hduser/C45/bank/*

14/11/24 13:30:03 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Found 174 items
drwxr-xr-x   - hduser supergroup          0 2014-11-24 13:17 /home/hduser/C45/bank/outputIntermediate/0
drwxr-xr-x   - hduser supergroup          0 2014-11-24 13:17 /home/hduser/C45/bank/outputIntermediate/1
.
.
.
drwxr-xr-x   - hduser supergroup          0 2014-11-24 13:19 /home/hduser/C45/bank/outputIntermediate/96
drwxr-xr-x   - hduser supergroup          0 2014-11-24 13:19 /home/hduser/C45/bank/outputIntermediate/97
drwxr-xr-x   - hduser supergroup          0 2014-11-24 13:19 /home/hduser/C45/bank/outputIntermediate/98
drwxr-xr-x   - hduser supergroup          0 2014-11-24 13:19 /home/hduser/C45/bank/outputIntermediate/99
ls: `/home/hduser/C45/bank/rule.txt': No such file or directory
```

I am confused by the last line. Is it that the directory tree is updated but file creation has failed?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: pls check the user by which you are creating this file ?

Comment: i have logged in as hduser and am running a jar in the hadoop file system